# What is the proper syntaxis when dealing with patch-here in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I've got the following code, but when trying to run it I get a message saying "expected a literal value", and it highlights *calidad*...
I'm guessing it is because there is a problem with how i am writting the brackets?

```
to check-if-dead
 if habitat = "escarabajo" [
  ask escarabajos [
      if count escarabajos-here > capacidad-de-carga-bosques [die] ; beetles that reach patches that already have a # above the carrying capacity die 
      if patch-here = [calidad "baja"] [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-baja [die]
      ]
      if patch-here = [calidad "alta" ] [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-alta [die]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

There is patches of high quality and patches with low quality in my universe, and I want the turtles to die with a certain probability (determined by a slider), depending on which patch they land...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `if [calidad] of patch-here = "baja"`:

```
to check-if-dead
  if habitat = "escarabajo" [
    ask escarabajos [
      if count escarabajos-here > capacidad-de-carga-bosques [die] ; beetles that reach patches that already have a # above the carrying capacity die 
      if [calidad] of patch-here = "baja" [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-baja [die]
      ]
      if [calidad] of patch-here = "alta" [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-alta [die]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

But note that turtles always live on a patch, so you are allowed to just reference the `patches-own` variable directly as a short-cut for this situation (same way you can use `pcolor` in a turtle context, too):

```
to check-if-dead
  if habitat = "escarabajo" [
    ask escarabajos [
      if count escarabajos-here > capacidad-de-carga-bosques [die] ; beetles that reach patches that already have a # above the carrying capacity die 
      if calidad = "baja" [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-baja [die]
      ]
      if calidad = "alta" [
        if random 100 > probabilidad-de-supervivencia-calidad-alta [die]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```